# .NET Core 3.1 URL not functioning correctly in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: asp.net-core

everyone. I'm following the tutorial here:
[Razor Pages with Entity Framework Core in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-rp/intro?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio)  using Core 3.1 and Visual Studio 2019, version 16.5.5.

I created a couple of models of my own (like "Assignments").

The problem I'm running into is when I am testing, the URLs do not appear correctly.

They are in my code as shown in the tutorial, like this:

```
<li class="nav-item">
                        <a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="/Courses/Index">Courses</a>
                    </li>
```

However, when I actually *run* the application to test it, the above URL shows up like this:

```
https://localhost:5001/?page=%2FCourses%2FIndex
```

And this is what the .cshtml.cs file looks like for Courses:

```
public class IndexModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly TestSchool.SchoolContext _context;

    public IndexModel(TestSchool.SchoolContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public IList<Course> Course { get; set; }

    public async Task OnGetAsync()
    {
        Course = await _context.Courses.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

I'm not even sure what I'm doing wrong. I'm assuming there's a configuration or something somewhere that I'm missing, but as I'm trying to learn .NET Core, I'm not entirely sure where to start looking.

Comment: Can you provide us with the location of the folder of Courses and the page where the link is located?

Comment: Yes. The "courses" folder is in MyProject --> Pages (so, MyProject --> Pages --> Courses), and the page with the links on it is the _Layout.cshtml page located in MyProject --> Views --> Shared, just like it is in the tutorial.

Comment: Is your project a core mvc or razor page? Why is your _Layout.cshtml page under `Views` folder ? The razor page only has the `Pages` folder instead of Views.

Comment: It's a Razor page. I basically started this project completely over because I couldn't find an answer, but if anyone knows the answer, I'll certainly be happy to view it, and it may help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Add `./url` in `asp-page` address.

```
<a class="nav-link text-dark" asp-area="" asp-page="./Courses/Index">Courses</a>
```